# Problemas al descargar pdf por Chrome PHP

Tags: php, html, pdf, google-chrome

Al momento de seleccionar un pdf el browser chrome me lo visualiza bien, pero si deseo descargarlo no me funciona, me descarga un archivo con el nombre de la pagina que es ver.php
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

index.php

```
var listar = function(year) {
            var table = $("#dt_cliente").DataTable({
                "order": [
                    [0, "desc"]
                ],
                "destroy": true,
                "ajax": {
                    "method": "POST",
                    "url": "inc/listar.php?anno=" + year //Año
                },
                "columns": [{
                    "data": "decreto"
                }, {
                    "data": "anno"
                }, {
                    "data": "materia",
                "searchable": true,
                "sortable": false
                }, {
                    "data": "pdf",
                    "searchable": false,
                    "sortable": false,
                    "render": function(pdf) {
                        if (!pdf) {
                            return "";
                        } else {
                            return '<a href="ver.php?pdf=' + pdf + '" target="_blank"><img src="img/pdf-icon.png"> Ver decreto</a>'
                        }
                    }
                }]
```

ver.php

```
<?php
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
readfile('file/'.$_GET['pdf']);
 ?>
```

Si utilizo mozilla funciona muy bien, que puede ser?
Saludos cordiales

http://transparencia.villalemana.cl/decreto/ aqui intento descargar los pdf en Chrome

Comment: Te refieres que no te lo descarga cuando presionas descargar en el visor?

Comment: http://transparencia.villalemana.cl/decreto/  si pones ver decreto y intanteas descargarlo te descargar un archivo ver.pdf

Comment: @MoteCL, ya lo probé en Chrome "Versión 66.0.3359.139 (Build oficial) (64 bits)" y funciona bien (la visualización y la descarga). URL: http://transparencia.villalemana.cl/decreto/ver.php?pdf=2018ad530.pdf

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave te logro descargar el archivo 2018ad530.pdf?

Comment: @MoteCL lo descargó como "Ver.pdf". Por favor [edit] su pregunta colocando el código de cómo especifica el nombre del archivo a descargar. Por ejemplo, en `index.php`, no se sabe cuál es el valor de `pdf `.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave uso un datatable para cargar los datos

Comment: @MoteCL lo único que se me ocurre es que investigue cómo especificar el nombre "no lo deje que lo determine el navegador". Siento no poder ayudarle "ya que no se de PHP", pero espero que encuentre la solución.

Comment: fijate este hilo : https://stackoverflow.com/a/20080402/1423096

Comment: @aloMalbarez le agrege esta linea de codigo   $filename='file/'.$_GET['pdf']; y   header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename='$filename'"); me descarga el archivo enseguida sin poder visualizarlo

Comment: y `header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=$filename);` ? si no funciona habras de hacer alguna acrobacia con `.htaccess` o `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`en el ver.php

Comment: funciono al agregar el header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=$filename);

Comment: @MoteCL, por favor, si encontraste la respuesta, publícala y acéptala. lee: [¿qué significa cuando una respuesta es aceptada?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1** con get: `ver.php?pdf=nombre.pdf`

Definiendo inline para que salga por navegador y filename para que tome el nombre original

```
<?php
$nombreDeArchivo = $_GET['pdf'];
$nombreDeArchivo = end(explode('/',$nombreDeArchivo));

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename='.$nombreDeArchivo);
readfile('file/'.$nombreDeArchivo);
?>
```

**2** usando path info: `ver.php/nombre.pdf`

```
<?php
$nombreDeArchivo = ltrim(isset($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'])?$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']:'ERROR','/');
$nombreDeArchivo = end(explode('/',$nombreDeArchivo));

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename='.$nombreDeArchivo);
readfile('file/'.$nombreDeArchivo);
 ?>
```

En los ejemplos filtro mínimamente el nombre de archivo, en tu caso si solo son pdf habria que chequear la extensión, si el archivo existe y esas cosas para que no haya agujeros de seguridad ni errores extraños.