# Como descargar un reporte en el navegador

Tags: php, dompdf

Uso dompdf, el problema es que muestra todo el contenido pdf en el navegador, lo que yo quiero es que desde un boton descargar directamente lo descargue al pc del cliente.

Comment: fijate esta pregunta respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/160579/81450

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenés que agregar los encabezados correspondientes en tu archivo PHP:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header("Content-type: application/pdf");
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=el_nombre_de_mi_archivo.pdf');
    readfile('file/el_nombre_de_mi_archivo.pdf');
?>
```

Saludos!